# Setting DataGridTextColumn Width

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, converters, ivalueconverter, datagridtextcolumn

I have a MVVM WPF application.

I have a DataGridTextColumn in a WPF datagrid. I want to bind its width property to a converter and pass to it its cell value. For this column, there are cases where all cells for this column are empty so I also want to set the column width to a fixed value, 20 (the same as its MinWidth) in case all cells are empty, otherwise 50. The problem is that converter is not being called.

To simplify and focus on the interesting parts I only post here the relevant code:

```
 <DataGrid  Grid.Row="1"                          
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfItems}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" 
               SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*" 
               >

<DataGridTextColumn 
      CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}"
      Binding="{Binding Path=EntryDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" 
      Header="Entry Date" 
      Width="{Binding Path=EntryDate, Converter={StaticResource ColumnWidthConverter}}"
      HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">

</DataGridTextColumn> 

 </DataGrid>
```

**Converter**:

```
public class ColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string cellContent= (string)value;

        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellContent.Trim()) ? 20 : 50);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My final goal is to set column width to 20 when all its cells are empty, otherwise set its width to 50. I thought that using a converter it will be a good idea but converter is never called. Why?

**UPDATE**:
Finllay I have done what @Andy suggests: bind a property from view model to datagridtextcolumn width property on view. This property on view model iterates over all column cells, and then set the width accordingly. See below. My problem is that this property 'EntryDateColumnWidth' on view model only fires first time when application is launched, then when calling OnPropertyChanged("EntryDateColumnWidth"), it is not raised.

**View model**:

```
public class MyMainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public DataGridLength EntryDateColumnWidth
  {
      get
      {
          bool isEmpty = this.MyListOfItems.TrueForAll(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.EntryDate.ToString().Trim()));

          return (isEmpty ? 20 : new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto));
      }
  }
}
```

Also, from view model, when I have set the list of items for the datagrid, I perform:

```
OnPropertyChanged("EntryDateColumnWidth");
```

This property returns a DataGridLength object because I need to set width to auto when any of the column cells is not empty.

**Note**: ViewModelBase is an abstract class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

**View**:

```
<DataGrid  Grid.Row="1"                          
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfItems}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" 
           SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*">

<DataGrid.Resources>
   <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn 
      CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}"
      Binding="{Binding Path=EntryDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" 
      Header="Entry Date" 
      Width="{Binding Data.EntryDateColumnWidth, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"
      HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">

</DataGridTextColumn> 

</DataGrid>
```

**Class BindingProxy**:

```
namespace MyApp.Classes
{
    public class BindingProxy : Freezable
    {
        #region Overrides of Freezable

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new BindingProxy();
        }

        #endregion

        public object Data
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

**Dependency object class**:

```
namespace My.WPF.App.Classes
{
    public class BridgeDO: DependencyObject
    {
        public DataGridLength DataComandaColWidth
        {
            get { return (DataGridLength)GetValue(DataComandaColWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataComandaColWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EntryDateColWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EntryDateColWidth", 
                                        typeof(DataGridLength), 
                                        typeof(BridgeDO),                                         
                                        new PropertyMetadata(new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto)));
    }
}
```

**Instance in the resource dictionary (DictionaryDO.xaml)**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.WPF.App.Classes">
    <local:BridgeDO x:Key="DO"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Merging it into resource dictionary (app.xaml)** :

```
<Application x:Class="My.WPF.Apps.MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.WPF.Apps.MyApp"
    StartupUri="Main.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionaries/DictionaryDO.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- Styles -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Window** :

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="My.WPF.Apps.MyApp.wMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Window.Resources>
   <!-- Resources -->
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid  Grid.Row="1"                          
           AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfItems}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" 
           SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*">

<DataGrid.Resources>
   <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn 
      CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCellStyle}"
      Binding="{Binding Path=EntryDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" 
      Header="Entry Date" 
      Width="{Binding EntryDateColWidth, Source={StaticResource DO}}"
      HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">

</DataGridTextColumn> 

</DataGrid>

</Window>
```

**View model**:

```
public class myMainViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
   private BridgeDO _do;
   public myMainViewModel(IView view)
   {
      _view = view;
      _do = Application.Current.Resources["DO"] as BridgeDO;            
   }


   private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork()
   {
      // Do some stuff
      SetColumnWidth();
   }


   private void SetColumnWidth()
   {
      _view.GetWindow().Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
       {
          bool isEmpty = this.MyListOfItems.TrueForAll(e => !e.EntryDate.HasValue);
          _do.SetValue(BridgeDO.EntryDateColWidthProperty, isEmpty ? new DataGridLength(22.0) : new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto));

            }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
   }
}
```

But column width is not being updated...

Comment: Where is entrydate and what is it anyhow? Your column is binding DataCommanda. From your description you'd have to iterate through all of them and check whether they're empty or not. You realise that  header of "Entry Date" won't fit in a 20 wide column?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as your other question?  Add a property to your viewmodel and use linq with trueforall to see if all the particular column is null. Then set your property. Use a datatrigger to set width or make it a double and bind width directly.

Comment: @Andy It was a mistake, see my update. EntryDate comes from Itemsource bound to the DataGrid. I mean despite all column cells are empty, the column width is as wide as its header title.

Comment: I understand that. You need to iterate the whole collection and check each entrydate. As I've explained. Forget the converter. Do it in your viewmodel. Add a viewmodel if you don't have one and put whatever itemssource is bound to in there. Then use linq to check whether all the entrydates are null and set a property.

Comment: @Andy I have done what you suggested using a property in view model. My problem now is that this property is never fired. See my last update.

Comment: I was forgetting something. You won't be able to get a reference to the viewmodel from the Datagridtextcolumn. It's not a control or anything in the visual tree.  https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: @Andy I have updated my post again. Now my problem is that  property 'EntryDateColumnWidth' on view model only fires first time when application is launched, afterwards when calling OnPropertyChanged("EntryDateColumnWidth"), it is not raised.

Comment: inotifypropertychanged doesn't apply to dependency properties. Raising propertychanged on a dp has no effect. There's metadata settings on dp. There's one says it'll effect UI. Something like affectsrender. Mark it with that. I don't know where you have your bindingproxy. You need to get at it from the VM so you could do something like make it a property of the vm. But the way you want this to work is your vm sets the dp. The column will then get it's value.

Comment: @Andy ok, i understand you. I need to create the dependency property from the view model and mark it with AffectsRender metadata. Then from my view model I update this dependency property and the UI automatically updates it because it is bound to it. The problem here is that my view model class needs to inherit DependyObject class and my view model class already inherits a class (ViewModelBase)...

Comment: Might be neater if that dependency object was in resources anyhow. You could stick it in a resource dictionary you merge in app.xaml. Grab it back out from application.current.resources in the vm and set the property on it. Or make it a static. I don't really like statics if any unit testing will touch them but this doesn't look like something you'd automate tests on anyhow.

Comment: @Andy could you post a little example on how to implement dependency object in resources and stick it in a resource dictionary? It seems interesting but sincerely I have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this demonstrates the principle of what I'm describing and it's a bit quick n dirty.
Define a dependency object as a new class.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace wpf_12
{
    public class BridgeDO : DependencyObject
    {
        public DataGridLength ColWidth
        {
            get { return (DataGridLength)GetValue(ColWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ColWidthProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ColWidth", typeof(DataGridLength), typeof(BridgeDO), new PropertyMetadata(new DataGridLength(20.0)));
    }
}
```

Create an instance in a resource dictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_12">
    <local:BridgeDO x:Key="DO"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Merge that resource dictionary in app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="wpf_12.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_12"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Quick and dirty viewmodel, this will change the column width to auto 6 seconds after it's instantiated.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace wpf_12
{
    public class MainWIndowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<object>
        {   new { Name="Billy Bob", ID=1},
            new { Name="Peter Parker", ID=2},
            new { Name="Sherlock Holmes", ID=2}
        };

        public MainWIndowViewModel()
        {
            ChangeWidth();
        }
        private async void ChangeWidth()
        {
            await Task.Delay(6000);
            var _do = Application.Current.Resources["DO"] as BridgeDO;
            _do.SetCurrentValue(BridgeDO.ColWidthProperty, new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto));
        }
    }
}
```

Use that in my window:

```
        Name="Window"
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWIndowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="{Binding ColWidth, Source={StaticResource DO}}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run this I start off with a narrow-ish column.  Sit there watching it for a while and it changes to auto width and widens.

Comment: A lot of thanks! I am trying your code. If I update the dependecy property from view model constructor it works. However if I set it from the point I need, within a background worker when it finishes its job just after datagrid itemsource is populated, property is set (no exception thrown) but the datagrid column width is not updated with the new value... Something in my code is wrong...I am trying to know what...

Comment: Also If Initially I set to DataGridLength(20.0) as a default value in BridgeDO class, when app starts, column width is set to 20.0 but after datagrid is populated this width is not respected, it is automactically set to auto, despite later in code I set again to the default 20.0. Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Sounds like you're over-writing something, the object or binding. Are you over-writing the binding by not using setcurrentvalue? Or over-writing the instance in resources? Changing the dp on a background thread?  The code I posted definitely works. The data loads and the column is narrow. 6 seconds later it grows wider.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.Tomorrow I will check whether I am over-writing something but I have exactly followed your example. The only difference is that I am using SetValue instead of SetCurrentValue. SetCurrentValue is only available since .NET Framework 4 and above.I am using NET 3.5 so this method does not exist.In .NET 3.5 I am using SetValue. I guess this does the same as SetCurrentValue.I create the instance once in the dictionary as in your example, then I merge the dictionary into app.xaml.Regarding the background worker, yes I use SetValue from it but using Dispatcher.CheckAccess first.

Comment: Regarding background worker: I have two datagrids. Dg1 and Dg2. Dg2 is the one where I want to set column width for one of its columns. Initially I load data into Dg1. Then when a row is selected in Dg1, I load data into Dg2. I load Dg2 using a background worker. Dg2 Itemsource property is bound to a view model property. The background worker loads data into this view model property and once I have loaded data into it I call SetValue to update Dg2 column width.

Comment: You're using setvalue rather than setcurrentvalue. That may be overwriting your binding.

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 and setcurrentvalue is not available. Setvalue is the equivalent in NET 3.5. So how to update value if setcurrentvalue is not available in .NET 3.5 and only setvalue is available? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I will try. But what's the difference between SetCurrentValue (NET >=4.0) and SetValue (.NET <=3.5)? According to the descriptions in msdn they do the same.

Comment: Read the part in setcurrentvalue about not breaking bindings. Then try and find that in setvalue. The descriptions on msdn are significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that using a converter it will be a good idea but converter is never called. Why?

Because the `DataGridTextColumn` inherits no `DataContext` and can't bind to the `EntryDate` property like that.

> My final goal is to set column width to 20 when all its cells are empty, otherwise set its width to 50.

Then you could iterate through all items in the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` and check the value of their `EntryDate` property, e.g.:

```
dgg.Loaded += (s, e) => 
{
    bool isEmpty = true;
    foreach(var item in dgg.Items.OfType<Item>())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EntryDate))
        {
            isEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //set the Width of the column (at index 0 in this sample)
    dgg.Columns[0].Width = isEmpty? 20 : 500;
};
```

Note: In this particular example I have assumed that `EntryDate` is indeed a `string`. If it's a `DateTime` or a `Nullable<DateTime>` you could check whether it equals `default(DateTime)` or `default(DateTime?)` respectively.

Comment: EntryDate bound to the width property and then passed to the converter comes from the ItemsSource bound to the datagrid.See my update above. It's not a property in the view model.

Comment: I know. What's your point? The column has no DataContext at all so binding won't work.

Comment: I mean, DataContext for this column is the same as the ItemSource, as EntryDate in this case comes from datagrid's ItemSource property set by MyListOfItems, so wpf knows the datacontext.

Comment: Once again: No. You cannot bind like that. Binding is a property of the DataGridColumn that the DataGrid uses when it creates the cells. What's the point of asking a question if you don't like the answer? Obviously you don't know how a DataGrid works.

Comment: The reason to ask this question is because I would like to know why the call to the converter was not working. So, ok, then how to pass the cell value to the converter? Also, apart from this, I have tried your solution as well, but when datagrid content changes load event is not raised.

Comment: Because the binding fails. And why would the Loaded event be raised when the content changes...?

Comment: Because I have one datagrid that depends on what is selected on the first datagrid. When some item is selected on first datagird,then second datagrid is populated. This second datagrid is what I am referring to in this post. It has a column that depending on some conditions, are columns' cells are empty, so in this second datagrid I set the column width according to this.

Comment: Is there any datagrid's event on which I can subscribe in order to detect when datagrid content changes? It would be interesting one event that is fired each time datagrid is loaded with different data.